# Is there something like a "table pointer"?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm a total SQL newbie. I have two temp tables with values, for example:

```
create table #MyTable1(...)
create table #MyTable2(...)
insert into #MyTable1(...)
values(...)
insert into #MyTable2(...)
values(...)
```

Now I wonder if it is possible to call both tables not directly but by using something like a "table pointer"? I need something like this:

```
MyTableVariable = #MyTable1
select * from MyTableVariable   /*outputs content of MyTable1*/
MyTableVariable = #MyTable2
select * from MyTableVariable   /*outputs content of MyTable2*/
```

Does an approach exist in SQL/TSQL?

Comment: Not sure if exists but it might also depend on DB server...Oracle? Informix?Mysql? Sql Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: But why? Do you want to alias the table name or is this some attempt to make the table referenced dynamic?

Comment: post the real question instead. this question looks like an attempt to implement the solution you found to an hidden issue/requirement/problem.

Comment: It is legitimate to have 2 very similar tables containing similar structures but different content. Simple example - lets say I have a table for current customers and one for old customers. I use the separation so as to get good performance for queries about current customers.   Take it as a given that I will know which table a customer is in. Without a table pointer I inevitably have to have duplicate code - either duplicate sprocs differing only by the table name, or alternatively one sproc with an if and the query almost duplicated in each fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in T-SQL there is no *table pointer*, but there is *dynamic SQL*:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(ID INT, Content VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES(1,'Test 1'),(2,'Test 2');

DECLARE @dynamicTablePointer VARCHAR(100)='#MyTable';

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT * FROM ' + @dynamicTablePointer;

EXEC(@cmd);
```

This has some restrictions (e.g. cannot be used in ad-hoc SQL, functions, views), but allows dynamic table references and column names.

Answer (score 2):

No SQL Server does not inherently support pointers this is partially due to the fact that Structure Query Languages are declarative in nature (you don't list commands or steps that must be performed instead you describe the desired result).  With this in mind tables are not complex C# or Java style objects that has to be passed from one method to the next, instead they are related data stored in a structured format on the database that can be queried by anyone with the necessary permissions, as such there really is no need to reference them via a pointer.

There are a couple of ways you can simulate the pointer style behavior described. One method for which you already have been provided a couple of examples is to simply make use of dynamic SQL and pass your table to the query as a string parameter. Another method would be to use synonym, see example below:

```
    CREATE SYNONYM [MyTableSynonym] FOR #Table1

    SELECT *
    FROM    [MyTableSynonym]

    DROP SYNONYM [MyTableSynonym]

    CREATE SYNONYM [MyTableSynonym] FOR #Table2

    SELECT *
    FROM    [MyTableSynonym]

    DROP SYNONYM [MyTableSynonym]
```

The above method is not recommended since we are now using Synonyms in a way there where not intended.

The real question though is what benefits has been realized with either method? The amount of code to query the two tables has increased, the complexity of the queries has increase, the potential for bugs in the code has increase and trying to debug queries of this nature will be a nightmare. Even if true pointer where supported I can only think of a handful of scenarios where it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL inside a properly designed stored procedure.
If you go with this approach don't forget to use add proper parameter definition to avoid SQL Injection.

```
create table #MyTable1(col1 int)
create table #MyTable2(col2 int)

DECLARE @MyTableVariable NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

--selecte from the first table
SET @MyTableVariable= '#MyTable1'
SET @SQLString =N'select * from '+@MyTableVariable+';';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;

--select from the second table
SET @MyTableVariable = '#MyTable2'
SET @SQLString =N'select * from '+@MyTableVariable+';';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

Answer (score 1):

A totally different approach would be to UNION both of your temp tables. 
This solution is applicable if both tables have the same columns structure, and you need to output all the data together. 
In this case, why not do it like this:

`SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM #table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM #table2`

Having said that, if the data structures (columns) are completely different, Dynamic SQL is your solution.